# Mock sensor data on Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Is there anyway I can create mock sensor data on watch emulator? Like heart rate, acceleration, .etc.
I have a real Gear Live, but want to make sure it works on round watches, and test there as well.
Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it on the Wear emulator, but you should be able to inject sensor data into the emulator: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can.**

Use synthetic data providers to simulate sensor data from Health Services and test your app as though an exercise were really happening.

**Considerations when using the emulator**

When using the Wear OS emulator, there are two options available for generating simulated data:

**Synthetic data providers**: Offers extensive options for data generation. This is the covered throughout the rest of this page.

To use synthetic data providers on the emulator, ensure [developer options](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging#enable-dev-options) are enabled.

**Emulator extended controls**: The emulator in Android Studio offers the extended controls panel, available by clicking the three dots in the button bar. From the extended controls, the developer can load in KML/GPX files to simulate location, or specify the behaviour of the heart rate sensor.

To use extended controls to generate data for health services, ensure that [sensor providers are enabled](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/synthetic-data#sensor).

**Supported metrics**

Synthetic data providers currently support the following metrics:

1. Heart rate
2. Step count per minute
3. GPS location (using a single default route)
4. Duration of the activity
5. Elevation and floors
6. Sleep state (asleep/awake)

For more information please refer the following.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/synthetic-data